# Как удалить из коллекции строки по определенной части?

Tags: c#

Есть коллекция , в коллекции строки вида:

```
stud1/name1?a=lend1223
stud/name2?b=lend356
stud/name3?v=lend56
```

надо удалить все дубликаты строк из этой коллекции строго по этой части: **"?a="** то есть от символа: "**?**" до символа: "**=**"

как это возможно реализовать по проще?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Выбрать элементы в ключ, по которым будут отрезаны дубликаты. Сгруппировать по этому ключу. Отобрать из каждой группы по одному элементу.

```
List<string> list = new List<string>(){
    "stud1/name1?a=lend1223",
    "stud/name12?a=lend1223",
    "stud/name2?b=lend356",
    "stud/name22?b=lend356",
    "stud/name3?v=lend56"
};

List<string> nlist = list.Select(p => new { key = new Regex("\\?(.)*=", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Match(p).Groups[1].Value, value = p })
    .GroupBy(p => p.key)
    .Select(p => p.First().value)
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
collection.Where((x, i) => 
  collection.Where((y, j) => 
    j < i && 
    y.Contains(
      x.Substring(x.IndexOf("?"), 
      1 + x.IndexOf("=") - x.IndexOf("?")))).Count() == 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string x = "bla-bla-bla";
int pos, pos2;
while ((pos = x.IndexOf('?')) !=-1 && ((pos2 = x.IndexOf('=')) !=-1))
    x = x.Substring(0,pos-1)+x.Substring(pos2+1);
```